# Properties of the sum or product of functions

Tags: functions, optimization

I have $m$ functions of $n$ variables, $f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ (where both $m$ and $n$ are finite), and I want to find the maximum (or the minimum) of:
\begin{equation}
G=\sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i(\bf{x})
\end{equation}
Can we say something *a priori* about the properties of $G$, properties that we can exploit for the optimization? 
For example, if all the $f_i$ are convex, then $G$ is convex as well, and this may 
help greatly in solving the problem. The same can be asked for:
\begin{equation}
H=\prod_{i=1}^{m}f_i(\bf{x})
\end{equation}

Thanks.

Comment: The sums and products are over m+1 functions. Go from $1$ to $m$, rather than from $0$. The only thing I can suggest is using [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers)